# Which green spectral line(s) are emitted in a Thomson tube?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

Related: [What is meant by boiling off electrons in a heater coil?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79074/2451)

In the Thomson tube we used in our class to produce an electron beam, the lab manual stated that the tube was filled with a low pressure argon gas. When the electrons collided with the argon gas, electrons in the gas molecules were excited and when they de-excite, green light is emitted. However, when one looks at the atomic spectra of argon, there are two green lines, as shown below.

[image]

Is one able to distinguished between these two green lines in this experiment or am I actually seeing both of these lines? I assume that because the Thomson tube sends in a range of electron velocities, that maybe its both green lines that I am seeing. However, I don't know for sure.

Comment: BTW it's a *Thomson* not a *Thompson* tube. Named after J. J. Thomson (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._J._Thomson).

Comment: @JohnRennie: My apologizes to the Thomson's and thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at best only a partial answer since I don't know for sure, but I would guess the tube contains a mixture of some gas (possibly argon) with a small amount of mercury vapour.

Effectively what you have is a [gas discharge lamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp), though I'd guess it's at a lower pressure than the usual gas discharge lamps because you don't want excessive electron scattering. These don't give you a single line, but rather you get a whole series of lines and the overall colour depends on which lines are strongest and contribute most to the light. Most gases tend to give blue/violet discharges - I'd guess your picture is of an argon discharge, and you can see that it's violet not green. I believe that adding a small amount of mercury vapour gives a blue/green light, which is why I suspect it's an argon/mercury mixture.

To be honest I'm not sure about this, and a quick Google didn't help much. Maybe it will give you somewhere to start from if you want to try following this up yourself.

Comment: Your answer has brought up several interesting questions. I looked up the Thomson tube's details and the LD Didactic company says it is only argon gas. Assuming this and getting permission of my TA for the course, I was able to look at the green beam using a hand held (high quality) diffraction grating and I only saw one line. So it is not both lines of the spectrum that I am seeing, but one of them. I assume it is the lower one, however, I don't know.

Comment: Regardless of the accelerating voltage of the beam, there is always a green line. I would have thought that at lower accelerating voltages, I would of gotten red lines (lower energy spectral lines) instead of the higher energy green lines of argon. But that is not the case. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Comment: Is is this equipment? http://www.ld-didactic.de/phk/gruppen.asp?PT=VP3.8.5.1&L=2 If so, it's not the gas glowing. The electron beam is hitting a phosphor (the screen with the grid drawn on it) and it's the phosphor that's glowing.

Comment: It seems that I gave you misinformation. The TA and lab manual for my class stated that the glass tube was filled with a low pressure argon gas, similar to an em tube (which I've never used before); so I looked up em tubes not Thomson tubes. I deeply apologize for this but being new to physics, I will make mistakes. From your comment I looked up how fluorescent screens work, and I did not understand how the green light is produced? Is it the same reason as before – electrons jump to a higher energy level and emit green light as they de-excite?

Comment: @LisaLee: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor